# I dont know how to fix my error for AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

it gives me the same error and I don't know how to fix it here it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/b41f205e56036d7a/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    car.append
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

---

```
while True:
  car = input("Choose one of the car brands we have recommended.")
  if car.lower() == "q":
    break
  else:
    price = float(input(f"Write a price for the brand of cars from those we have offered you in order to choose which car from these brands to offer you. {car}: $"))
    car.append(car)
    price.append(price)
    
print("----- YOUR CARS -----")

for car in car:
  print(car)
```

Comment: What do you expect `car.append(car)` to do? `car` is a string and has no `append` method - as the error message tells you. I think you want to define and use a list called `cars`.

Comment: As the error clearly says that strings do not have append method. You can use '+' operator or join.

Comment: May be you wanted to do something like cars = []  then take input in car variable and then do cars.append(car)

Comment: Better naming can help avoid problems like this. Use singular names for variables containing one item, plural names for variables containing multiple items. Then you would have `for car in cars:`

Answer (score 1):

The variable car that you are using is a string so it does not have an append method. You need to create other variables that store the cars and prices. E.G

```
car_list = []
price_list = []

while True:
  car = input("Choose one of the car brands we have recommended.")
  if car.lower() == "q":
    break
  else:
    price = float(input(f"Write a price for the brand of cars from those we have offered you in order to choose which car from these brands to offer you. {car}: $"))
    car_list.append(car)
    price_list.append(price)
    
print("----- YOUR CARS -----")

for car in car_list:
  print(car)
```

Comment: The idea is good, the naming of the variables is terrible. Don't put data types in the name of the variable. Do you really want to rename everything if you later decide to make an own container class? `car_list` should simply be `cars`.